# Object.includes is not a function in old Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, webview, yandex-maps

I'm testing WebView on different devices. 
In the old version (WebView in com.com.com (39.0.0.0)), this function does not work:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON( data );
    console.log(obj);
    objectManager.setFilter(function(geoObject) { 
        return obj.includes(geoObject.id);   <---- 1839 Error
    });
```

Logs:

```
VM203 cmap-ya-android.js:1837 ["25", "59", "63"]
VM203 cmap-ya-android.js:1839 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
VM203 cmap-ya-android.js:1839 (anonymous function)
......
```

Everything is OK in the new Chrome: WebView in com.com.com (69.0.3497.100)

This method filters the display of markers on the map according to the documentation:

https://tech.yandex.com.tr/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#method_detail__setFilter-param-filterFunction
and
https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/setfilter-peredat-massiv-dannykh

Tell me, how can I adapt Object.include for older devices?
(Or create a filter that will work in all versions)

Comment: It's actually Array.includes. You have to include polyfills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes older browsers do not support Array.prototype.includes. 
Please rewrite the code using indexOf or use a polyfill for the same.

here you can achieve the same using

```
var obj = $.parseJSON( data );
console.log(obj);
objectManager.setFilter(function(geoObject) { 
    return obj.indexOf(geoObject.id) > -1;  
});
```

Comment: Thank you It is a simple and optimal solution for single use.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `obj` variable is actually an array, as seen in the first line of your logs. This means you are using [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of Object.includes. You can support older browsers by including [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) from the Mozilla JS docs in your project. This will add an implementation for `Array.includes` if it does not already exist.

When you need support for a more recent browser feature in older browsers, you can always search for [polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)).

---

In case the link with the polyfill will ever be dead, here is the code from that page:

```js
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
    value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If len is 0, return false.
      if (len === 0) {
        return false;
      }

      // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
      //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
      var n = fromIndex | 0;

      // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
      //  a. Let k be n.
      // 6. Else n < 0,
      //  a. Let k be len + n.
      //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
      var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

      // 7. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
        // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
        // c. Increase k by 1.
        // NOTE: === provides the correct "SameValueZero" comparison needed here.
        if (o[k] === searchElement) {
          return true;
        }
        k++;
      }

      // 8. Return false
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution. It works, but I think for the sake of one use, in my case, it’s better to apply the proposed @Pranav Ramachandran